# I want export csv file without "b"

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I want export csv file in mysql table

My code is:

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

       def importcsv():
            mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='me', passwd='1234', db='Data1', use_unicode=0, charset='utf8')
            cursor = mydb.cursor()
            csv_data = csv.reader(open('input.csv', newline='', encoding='utf8'))
            for row in csv_data:
                cursor.execute('INSERT INTO sensor(Date, Time, Data)' 'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")', row)
            mydb.commit()
            cursor.close()
            print ("CSV has been imported into the database")

       def exportcsv():
           mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='me', passwd='1234', db='Data1', use_unicode=0, charset='utf8')
           cursor = mydb.cursor()
           cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM sensor")

           with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
                    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')
                    csv_writer.writerow([ i[0] for i in cursor.description ]) 
                    csv_writer.writerows(cursor.fetchall())
                mydb.commit()
                cursor.close()
                print ("CSV has been exported into the database")
```

It works, but out.csv's data is

- date/time/data(header)
- b"'data value'"/b"'time value'"/b"'data value'"
- b"'data value'"/b"'time value'"/b"'data value'"

how can I export csv file like

- date/time/data(header)
- date value/time value/data value
- date value/time value/data value

input.csv's content is

date time data(header)

2017/01/01 12:00 1

2017/01/02 13:00 2

Comment: What field is it in the database and what exactly is the content. Seems like you have binary literals there?

Comment: Database and Table's Collation are utf8_unicode_ci and Table type is TEXT. All content is number and symbol, example) 21:33

Comment: You fetch all rows and put them straight into CSV (`csv_writer.writerows(cursor.fetchall())`). If you put the result fields each in an array (or tuple or whatever it is called in python), you can apply the solution from sky_1.

Comment: I also said sky_1, I can not understand how to use the underlying code...

Comment: But he gave you an example! And I told you where to apply the decoding. You have to do the very basic on your own. Stop expecting others doing all the work for you.

Comment: Btw you don't need Python at all. Simply use MySQL `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`.

Answer (score 2):

actually, the data that you are trying to fetch from MySQL is in byte string format you have to decode it to string format to get rid of the b you can try something like this.

`b"your bytecode string".decode()`

Comment: I'm Python programming beginner.
For that reason, I do not know how to use that code I taught.

May you give an example?